# What is this book about a girl who discovers she is a battle robot?

Tags: story-identification

A girl was a robot in disguise and her "mom" was her engineer. She was a battle robot and she would've killed millions if it wasn't for her mom. Then they get found out, go on the run, her mom gets kidnapped and she has to fight with other better versions of her made by her "dad". She escapes and swears revenge because her mom is dead. This doesn't do it justice

The way she finds out she's a robot is that she goes on a date with a guy at a carnival and she trips and falls exposing her wires.

Comment: It's probably worth looking through this [list of points](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/40437) to include in story-id questions to see if they help you remember any more details. Most importantly, where and when you might have read this would be helpful.

Comment: Only thing I can think of that I've read like this is vN: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13033939-vn it's not a great match though.

Comment: Can you remember where you read this? Was it a published novel, or something you read online?

Answer (score 7):

I was just looking and found it. It is: *[MILA 2.0](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10222362-mila-2-0)* by Debra Driza

[image: Cover image]

> Mila was never meant to learn the truth about her identity. She was a girl living with her mother in a small Minnesota town. She was supposed to forget her past—that she was built in a secret computer science lab and programmed to do things real people would never do.
>
> Now she has no choice but to run—from the dangerous operatives who want her terminated because she knows too much and from a mysterious group that wants to capture her alive and unlock her advanced technology. However, what Mila’s becoming is beyond anyone’s imagination, including her own, and it just might save her life.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you provide details of this that show how it matches?

Comment: I took the liberty of linking to Goodreads and quoting a summary. If you can provide more matched details, please [edit] them in.